# Slow and frequently error when get content script

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-status-code-500

I need to get content from this URL:

Desktop version: http://news.go.vn/bong-da/tin-2251140/pep-guardiola-bi-mat-gap-gdtt-man-city-o-barcelona.htm

Mobile version: http://m.go.vn/news/bong-da/tin-2251140/pep-guardiola-bi-mat-gap-gdtt-man-city-o-barcelona.htm

I need title, og:image, description, and text content. Here my script: http://pastebin.com/bFrtMqVi

Script running live here: http://bongdatv.net/news.php?url=/bong-da/tin-2251140/pep-guardiola-bi-mat-gap-gdtt-man-city-o-barcelona.htm

But script running very slow and frequently hit 500 Internal Server Error. I think problem happen when my server trying connect to remote server but I don't know why.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just have no idea this is a bad question ....